# Is Dart statically compiled, or is code interpetted at runtime as it's parsed and loaded into the VM?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to understand why adding traits to Dart would cause the shape of objects in memory to change, and am therefore curious how it loads in code right now.

Comment: How it's implemented is, well, an implementation detail. Any of the options you name, and many more are feasible. You can ask what a specific implementation is doing, but this is unlikely to solve your actual problem. So you should just describe that directly :-)

Comment: The terminology you are using it a bit confusing to me but.  I would say that Dart improves speed by knowing the relative size of an Object unless that object is specifically derived from Expando<> https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/Expando.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Is there anything I can do to make my question more specific? I suppose what I'm really trying to understand is if Dart code run by the VM is statically compiled (like C, C++, Java, etc.), or if it's interpretted (like JavaScript, Ruby, Python).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dart is a dynamically typed language that generates its own machine language equivalents straight from source code with no intermediate byte-code step.  There is no generic bytecode (like the JVM or llvm) and instead it is directly compiled into machine code.

I would add that despite compiling straight to machine code, the language itself is not designed in a way that would allow a C/C++ style compiler to effectively generate fast efficient code.  This is by design as Dart seems to be an attempt to fill the gap between JavaScript and Java rather than the gap between Java and C/C++. Dart addresses many issues that make JavaScript hard to optimize most importantly typing of numeric variables.

There are some efforts to port the Dart environment to various platforms beyond Windows/Mac/Linux but I have yet to see an actual straight to machine language compiler for Dart. That doesn't mean they don't exist, I just haven't seen anything other than ports of the Linux Dart environment onto Beagleboard and other small Linux distros.

From the Dart FAQ

> Q. Why didn’t Google build a bytecode VM targetable by multiple
>   languages including Dart? Each approach has advantages and
>   disadvantages, but we feel that in the context of Dart it made sense
>   to build a language-specific VM for the following reasons:
>
> Google already works on a multi-language bytecode: LLVM bitcode in
>   PNaCl.
>
> Even if a bytecode VM is specialized for Dart, a language VM will be
>   simpler and faster because it can work under stronger assumptions—for
>   instance, a structured control flow. These assumptions make the
>   implementation cleaner and optimizations easier.
>
> A general-purpose bytecode VM would be even larger and slower, as it
>   generalizes assumptions and adds functionality that for Dart is dead
>   code: for example, multithreading with a shared heap.
>
> No bytecode VM is truly general-purpose; they all make assumptions
>   that privilege some class of languages. A language VM leaves more room
>   to improve the VM and make deep changes to optimization of the
>   language. Some Dart engineers wrote an article talking about the VM
>   question in more detail.

A pretty good presentation on [Compiling Dart to Efficient 
Machine Code](https://www.dartlang.org/slides/2013/04/compiling-dart-to-efficient-machine-code.pdf)